# How can I confirm that Eclipse content assist works in Corrosion?

Tags: eclipse, rust

I thought I'd pick up Rust, so I installed it alongside Corrosion for Eclipse. Corrosion's description reads:

> Corrosion provides a rich and smart Rust editor with: - Syntax highlighting (using TextMate grammar) and Error reporting, Hover. **Content assist**. Jump to references, Code Outline,  Formatting... provided by the Rust Language Server

I've made sure to install RLS, and autocomplete seems to work without any problems in IntelliJ IDEA so I assume the install was successful.

The RLS setting in Eclipse is set to "Use Rustup" — not really sure what that entails. The only warning (about missing RLS) on Eclipse's settings page for Rust went away as soon as I installed RLS, so I assume it detected it.

Despite this nothing happens when pressing ^Space, which is the currently bound shortcut for content assist (e.g. after typing `use std::` or similar). Since I don't know what to expect from Corrosion I don't know if there's a problem or how to troubleshoot it.

What should I expect from this Content Assist?

```
$ cargo --version
cargo 1.29.0 (524a578d7 2018-08-05)
$ rustc --version
rustc 1.29.2 (17a9dc751 2018-10-05)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **proposals** of the content assist come **via** [**Language Server Protocol** (LSP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Server_Protocol) **from Rust**, Eclipse Corrosion only displays them. To be more precise, the executable `rls` (**r**ust **l**anguage **s**erver), which is part of a rust version, makes the proposals via LSP.

Therefore the proposals made **depends on the Rust version**. With Rustup you can install several versions in parallel and keep them up to date.

With the following simple code snippet you can check if Eclipse Corrision is configured correctly and LSP works:

```
fn main() {
    let foo = 1;
    {
        let foo = 2;
        println!("{}", foo);
    }
    println!("{}", foo);
}
```

If the cursor is set to the first `foo`, the first and the last `foo`, but not the two inner ones, should be highlighted (which is also implemented via LSP):

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed. And I can now conclude that it doesn't work — no highlighting at all takes place.

Comment: I see. I guess you have to fix something in _Window > Preferences: Rust_ or something is wrong with your Rust installation or both don't fit together. On Windows, _Rust Language Server Location_ set to _Other installation_ with  the `rls` path `C:\Users\User\.rustup\toolchains\beta-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\bin\rls.exe` works for me.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm on macOS, but changing Rust Language Server Location from the default "Use Rustup" to the pre-filled values of "Other installation" and relaunching seems to have done the trick. Highlighting works, and ^Space as well. I'm not sure why the default was broken — rustup is installed and working.

Comment: Maybe you first have to [install and activate a toolchain via Rustup (on the command line)](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rustup.rs/blob/master/README.md) to be able to use the _Use Rustup_ preference.

Answer (score 0):

What finally solved the underlying problem was to change the Rust Language Server Location from the default "Use Rustup" to the pre-filled values of "Other installation" and relaunching.

I don't know what the problem was though.

*It turned out that the actual symbol highlighting discussed above is broken in Eclipse's dark theme (white text on white background), <s>with no way of changing it in preferences</s> there is an obscure setting for this (see @howlger's comment), so in the end Eclipse turned out to <s>not be a serious contender</s> be a real hassle. Just a warning if you, like me, has dark theme as a requirement.*

Comment: The background color of these occurrences can be configured in _Window > Preferences: General > Editors > Text Editors > Annotations: LSP Text Occurrences_. Or right-click and choose _Switch to Theme... > Monokai_. Please report this issue here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=LSP4E&component=General

Comment: @howlger Oh wow, you're spot on, there it is. I Googled and experimented in two separate color preference panels, but came up empty. I wouldn't have found that in a hundred years. Regarding the bug, feel free to report it — I'm currently awaiting resolution of a bug in the handling of accounts on eclipse.org before I decide on whether or not I'll keep using my account.

Comment: If someone wants to become a hero and fix the bug (which affects not only Eclipse Corrision), Eclipse EclEmma had the same problem (annotation color not adapted for dark theme): https://github.com/eclipse/eclemma/commit/db992c330651fc29391e3f8c22f484135a7a1cd1

Comment: I reported the issue and contributed a fix (even though I prefer the light theme myself for ergonomic reasons): see [Eclipse bug 540531](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=540531). It turned out that everything was there, but only one file was forgotten to include in the build. Such an issue is only visible with the plug-in built, not during development. Unfortunately, the error was not reported earlier. There is also a [workaround](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=540531#c2) if you don't want to wait for it until the next release.

Comment: @howlger  nice. Thanks for the suggestion — I just changed the color, it works reasonably well for now. Dark theme is only necessary in the evenings. If I could I would have it switch automatically at a specific time, but since not even macOS seems to have thought about this obvious thing I'll just have it enabled permanently :)