# Eclipse RLS Configuration file missing?

Tags: eclipse, rust, rust-language-server

I have installed Eclipse for Rust and would like to use it for development. However, the content assist by RLS (such as code completion and highlighting) doesn’t work. RLS can't seem to find `racer` or `rustc`.

As I was looking at the settings for Rust (Window > Preferences > Rust), I noticed that the RLS config is pointing to a nonexistent file at ~/.cargo/rls.conf. Is this a problem? If so, how do I fix it? If not, what steps can I take to troubleshoot RLS?

I am currently using Ubuntu 18.04 and Eclipse Photon.

Comment: Please upgrade from Photon to 2018-09 (improvements have been made in this area). What are your exact settings in _Window > Preferences: Rust_? I guess, the location for RLS must set to something like `~/.rustup/toolchains/<toolchain>/bin/rls` (see [my answer here for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52925073/6505250)).

Comment: The deleted answer was linking to [this github issue](https://github.com/eclipse/corrosion/issues/186), which does look relevant. The final comment includes workaround steps.

Comment: This problem continues to exist in the 2018-09 version. The IDE keeps looking for a rls.conf file that does not exist and keeps prompting the user to specify one. In other words, this bug has never been fixed.

Comment: @FactorThree ... and also in the 2020-03 version :(

Answer (score 5):

Now in June 2020, the bug still shows in Eclipse 2020-03. I'll copy-paste the [GitHub comment](https://github.com/eclipse/corrosion/issues/186#issuecomment-532515836) that made it work:

```
rustup component add rls
```

Restart Eclipse and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest Corrosion plugin version to date (1.20) there is a new option right below the error messages to download and install cargo, rustup and rust-analyzer to prevent this from happening again.

Comment: but it doesnt work, everytime I restart my IDE, those buttons show up again